# QuickBooks Online (QBO) API Retrieve Deleted Bills

Tags: api, quickbooks, audit, audit-trail, audit-logging

Does the QuickBooks Online (QBO) API have the ability to query for objects that have been deleted? For example, I would like to query for bills that have been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

It does, yes, BUT the web service to fetch that data is intended only for BETA use.

Here's a link to the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/changedatadeleted